# NSTimer Value does not update UILabel? in SWIFT

Tags: swift, uilabel, nstimer

I am trying to update a label using the `NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval` method although the timer works fine my label is not changing as it should, can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? code:

```
class Questions: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    var timerVal = 10
    var timerLbl :UILabel!
    var timer:NSTimer!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

      startTimer()
    }


    func timerLabel() {
        var timerLbl = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(250, 20, 50, 50))
        timerLbl.text = "\(10)"
        timerLbl.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        timerLbl.font = UIFont(name: Font.FuturaBlack, size: 30)
        timerLbl.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center

        view.addSubview(timerLbl)
    }

    func updateTimer(dt:NSTimer) {
        timerVal--
        if timerVal == 0{
           timerVal = 11
        }else if timerVal < 0{
            timer.invalidate()
        } else{
            println(timerString) //PRINTS CORRECT AS THE TIMER DECREASES BY ONE SECOND
            timerLbl.text = "\(timerVal)" //NOTHING HAPPENS ON THE LABEL
        }
    }

    func startTimer(){
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: Selector("updateTimer:"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

}
```

Comment: where do you call timerLabel() ? does the label print anything to begin with ?

Answer (score 1):

the function timerLabel which creates your timerLbl is never called.

Comment: Apologies that is inside the view did load let me amend

Comment: Thanks I have sorted it now, I was creating the timerLbl twice, once in my viewDidLoad and once in the timerLabel Function. Thanks your answer woke me up!